# How many cubic bipartite graphs can we create?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

A cubic graph is a graph, whose vertices are all of degree 3. 
A bicubic graph is a cubic graph that is bipartite.

The picture below shows the smallest bicubic graph. The only one with 6 vertices.

[image]

It's easy to notice that every bicubic graph has an even number of vertices. 
My question is: **how many bicubic graphs of n vertices are there?**

Comment: See [OEIS sequence A008325](https://oeis.org/A008325).  Since this sequence has keyword "hard" and the Data only goes up to $n=14$, it seems there isn't a simple answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like @Robert said in the comment, the problem is hard. The only known solution is up to n = 28:

```
n  bicubic(n)
6  1
8  1
10 2
12 6
14 14
16 41
18 157
20 725
22 4196
24 29816
26 246644
28 2297075
30 23503477
32 260265023
```

Comment: As it happens, OEIS already contained the necessary information that [standard techniques](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiddellsFormula.html) suffice to add `30 23503477` and `32 260265023` to that list.